# How to migrate a custom plugin that shows a modal popup using vue 2 before to vue 3

Tags: vue.js

**AppModal.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="modal-wrapper" v-if="visible">
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ text }}</p>
    <div class="modal-buttons">
      <button class="modal-button" @click="hide">Close</button>
      <button class="modal-button" @click="confirm">Confirm</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      visible: false, 
      title: '',
      text: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    hide() {
      this.visible = false;
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

**Modal.js (plugin)**

```
import AppModal from 'AppModal.vue'

const Modal = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    this.EventBus = new Vue()
    Vue.component('app-modal', AppModal)
    Vue.prototype.$modal = {
      show(params) {
        Modal.EventBus.$emit('show', params)
      }
    }
  }
}

export default Modal
```

**main.js**

```
import Modal from 'plugin.js'
// ...
Vue.use(Modal)
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    // ... 
    <app-modal/>
  </div>
</template>
```

I have written a custom plugins with the above structure in vue 2, now i wanted to migrate it to vue 3 context

I have tried with using app.config.globalProperties and using provide/inject in vue 3, but it not really workings, now the function is able to call, but the modal popup is not showing

Comment: Vue 3 is no longer able to play the role of global event bus - you will need to use [mitt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mitt) or craft your own event bus. Also, you should replace `Vue.prototype` with `app.config.globalProperties`